# Values not written to vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm trying to read pairs values from a file in the constructor of an object.

The file looks like this:

```
4
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

The first number is number of pairs to read.

In some of the lines the values seem to have been correctly written into the vector. In the next they are gone. I am totally confused

```
inline
BaseInterpolator::BaseInterpolator(std::string data_file_name)
{
    std::ifstream in_file(data_file_name);
    if (!in_file) {
        std::cerr << "Can't open input file " << data_file_name << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    size_t n;
    in_file >> n;
    xs_.reserve(n);
    ys_.reserve(n);

    size_t i = 0;
    while(in_file >> xs_[i] >> ys_[i])
    {
        // this line prints correct values i.e. 1 1, 2 2, 3 3, 4 4
        std::cout << xs_[i] << " " << ys_[i] << std::endl;
        // this lines prints xs_.size() = 0
        std::cout <<  "xs_.size() = " << xs_.size() << std::endl;
        if(i + 1 < n)
            i += 1;
        else
            break;
        // this line prints 0 0, 0 0, 0 0
        std::cout << xs_[i] << " " << ys_[i] << std::endl;
    }
    // this line prints correct values i.e. 4 4    
    std::cout << xs_[i] << " " << ys_[i] << std::endl;
    // this lines prints xs_.size() = 0
    std::cout <<  "xs_.size() = " << xs_.size() << std::endl;
}
```

The class is defined thus:

```
class BaseInterpolator
{
public:
    ~BaseInterpolator();
    BaseInterpolator();
    BaseInterpolator(std::vector<double> &xs, std::vector<double> &ys);
    BaseInterpolator(std::string data_file_name);

    virtual int interpolate(std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &fx) = 0;
    virtual int interpolate(std::string input_file_name,
                        std::string output_file_name) = 0;


protected:
    std::vector<double> xs_;
    std::vector<double> ys_;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're experiencing undefined behaviour. It seems like it's half working, but that's twice as bad as not working at all.

The problem is this:

```
xs_.reserve(n);
ys_.reserve(n);
```

You are only *reserving* a size, not *creating* it.
Replace it by :

```
xs_.resize(n);
ys_.resize(n);
```

Now, `xs[i]` with `i < n` is actually valid.

If in doubt, use `xs_.at(i)` instead of `xs_[i]`. It performs an additional boundary check which saves you the trouble from debugging without knowing where to start.

Comment: Just let me see if I got this straight. The operator[] makes no checks and goes directly to what the underlying array would be and writes the value there, and doesn't even touch the element count. If I wanted to use resize I should have used push_back which would create the space if needed and increased the element count, right?

Comment: @hugoc. Yes, additionally, if you access with `[]` outside of the range `[0, v.size)`, then it is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're using `reserve()`, which increases capacity (storage space), but does not increase the size of the vector (i.e. it does not add any objects into it). You should use `resize()` instead. This will take care of `size()` being 0.
2. You're printing the `xs_[i]` and `ys_[i]` *after* you increment `i`. It's natural those will be 0 (or perhaps a random value) - you haven't initialised them yet.

Answer (score 0):

`vector::reserve` reserve space for further operation but don't change the size of the vector, you should use `vector::resize`.